# Terraform dynamic block in a template for nested values

Tags: templates, terraform

I would be appreciated for help or any idea on this task.
As you may see in locals.var `Application` and `Environment` keys have different values.
But as the result JSON file, these values are similar for both keys.
How to set correct corresponding values?

I guess `value_tag` should be set dynamically. `for_each` - creates a lot of files. `Dynamically block` looks don't work for this. Also, I need it all in one JSON file.

**Incorrect result**

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Application",
                        "Environment"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Application": [
                        "development",
                        "production"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
                        "development",
                        "production"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Correct result should be like this**

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Application",
                        "Environment"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Application": [
                        "app-01",
                        "app-02"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
                        "development",
                        "production"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```hcl
locals {
  enforce_tag = {
    Environment = {
      env01 = "development"
      env02 = "production"
    }
      Application = {
        app01 = "app-01"
        app02 = "app-02"
      }
  }
}
```

```hcl
data "template_file" "enforcetags" {
  template = templatefile("${path.module}/enforcetags.tpl",
    {
      key_tag = [for key, value in local.enforce_tag : key]
      value_tag   = local.enforce_tag.Environment
    }
  )
}
```

Template file:

```hcl
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": ${jsonencode([for key in key_tag : "${key}"
                        ])
                    }
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": ${jsonencode(
                                {for key in key_tag: "aws:RequestTag/${key}" => value_tag
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but a few things are missing. First comes some explanation, below you can find what I believe is the solution to your problem.

With this:

```
  value_tag   = local.enforce_tag.Environment
```

you only ever touch the `Environment` map, there's no reference to the `Application` map. Instead you can use this to pass both these maps (a map of 2 maps):

```
      value_tag   = local.enforce_tag
```

To avoid confusion let's call them:

- the big map called `enforce_tag` consisting of the following:
- the first small map (for environments)
- the second small map (for applications)

Then in order to use it properly in the template, when iterating over your tags (`Application`, `Environment`) you need to take respective **small** map for relevant tag:

```
value_tag[key]
```

And the last thing is that you don't seem to ever use the keys in the small maps (i.e. nowhere in your desired output I can see `env01` or `app02`). Nevertheless, maybe you need it this way for other reasons. If so, you are interested only in the **values** of the small maps. Not the whole maps, i.e.

```
values(value_tag[key])
```

---

In short, the following should work:

Terraform

```
data "template_file" "enforcetags" {
  template = templatefile("${path.module}/enforcetags.tpl",
    {
      key_tag = [for key, value in local.enforce_tag : key]
      value_tag   = local.enforce_tag
    }
  )
}
```

Template fragment

```
"StringEqualsIfExists": ${jsonencode(
        {for key in key_tag: "aws:RequestTag/${key}" => values(value_tag[key])}
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Grzegorz. This great lesson for me looks like a kind of magic for me :)

I used `env01` and `app02` in locals because don't know how to better organize these variables.

Comment: The "small maps" could be converted to lists. So that your _locals_ definition is simplified and the code in `StringEqualsIfExists` too.